# On 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect' filter, get the added/modified cart item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the filter `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` to redirect users to a custom page when they click the "Add to Cart" button in WooCommerce.

This function works to redirect to '/opie'

```
function xc_add_to_cart_redirect_to_opie() {

    global $woocommerce;

    // Remove the default `Added to cart` message
    wc_clear_notices();

    $url = get_site_url() . '/opie/';

    return $url;

}
```

The problem I am having is that I want to get properties of the currently being added/modified cart item. I will use this information in an http request I send to another service.

I thought I would be able to do this using the Cart object and getting the last item in the cart array. Something like:

```
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$lastItemAdded = end($items);
```

And then I'd pull the values I need from $lastItemAdded.

However, this doesn't work, because if the user adds a product that already exists in their cart, WooCommerce augments the product quantity, but does not shuffle this cart item to the end position in the array.

In other words, the `end($items)` will only work if the item being added is a new item and not one being updated with additional quantity.

I've also tried using the filter hook `woocommerce_add_cart_item` – this does return the last item added, and may be a better approach than the `end($items)` method, but again, when the item is already in the cart and quantities are only being modified on add-to-cart, this hook is not triggered, so I can't reference the properties of the most recently added/modified cart item.

My question therefore is the following: when hooking with the filter `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` is there any way to reliably get the cart item that has just been added *or* modified to the cart?

Comment: What details you need from cart item? in `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` itself has couple of parameters one is url and another is `product object`, here you get directly product object(not sure here why you want cart item, use product object instead - this is the one is going to add it into the cart) `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', $url, $adding_to_cart );` this is the filter provided by woocommerce with couple of parameters($adding_to_cart is product object).

Comment: @VigneshPichamani - thanks. Unfortunately I need the last added cart item because it has a user-uploaded image URL (via Product Addons), and I need the URL of that uploaded image so that I can pass it via HTTP to another service.

Comment: Is there any way, when calling `add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', array( $this, 'xc_add_to_cart_redirect_to_opie' ))` I could add an additional parameter (an ID or the entire cart object)? That way, I could pass the info I need to the redirect page and take it from there.

Comment: instead of filter, try action `do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );`

Comment: If the cart update with any quantity then use this action `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', $cart_item_key, $quantity, $old_quantity, $this );`

Answer (score 0):

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); 
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' );
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                        <td class="product-remove">
                            <?php
                                // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                    '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                    esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                    __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                    esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                    esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                ), $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <?php
                        $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        } else {
                            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
                        } else {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
                        }

                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        // Meta data.
                        echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.

                        // Backorder notification.
                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                            $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                        } else {
                            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                'min_value'    => '0',
                                'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
                            ), $_product, false );
                        }

                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
```